# Manually force sync on AppleRAID 1

Tags: raid

I'd like to force a sync or repair on my AppleRAID set as part of a regular maintence. Under Linux (md) I can do this by writing to control devices. Diskutil does not seem to offer me such an option.

Answer (score 1):

Open Disk Utility, select the RAID set and then click on RAID. Then click on Rebuild.

Comment: I don't see this unless the array degrades.